# Error running 'java': Default Activity not found in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

this is app/.../AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

and java/.../AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

I think this is a simple error but can anybody give me steps to solve it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need two manifest files?

Comment: yes, it was my fault.i am working on OpenCV and in the tutorials, they said to import java in SDK of open cv but that was wrong i needed to import the whole SDK of open cv . and i didnot remove java from the modules. I apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

your app using  java/.../AndroidManifest.xml

and you put mainActivity in app/.../AndroidManifest.xml

put application tag >>  with body

in app/.../AndroidManifest.xml

but why you using two Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file must need **one Application Tag** and that Application tag must need **one Default Activity**

Generally manifest files needs to be in **app/manifest** folder. and you also have that ..

but dont know why you are using blank manifest file in java folder.

Generally apps need only one Manifest file ( if you are not using any library , third party libs ..etc).